# SPICE model of coupled inductor

Tags: inductor, spice

[image: two leakage inductance model]

I want to write a spice model of a coupled inductor.
I’m wondering how to find N1:N2 in the figure below.
I have the same windings but different inductances in my two coils. 
Is N1:N2 equal to 1:1 or \$\sqrt{L1}\$:\$\sqrt{L2}\$?

I also found the SPICE syntax of a coupled choke.
For example,
L1 1 2 1u
L2 3 4 5u
K1 L1 L2 0.6

Can this example get the same result to the model below?

Comment: N1:N2 is probably the transformer ratio so it could be 1:1 but it does not have to be. Maybe this article will help: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/lt-journal/LTMag-V16N3-23-LTspice_Transformers-MikeEngelhardt.pdf  Yes it's about LTSpice but the same principles will apply to Spice.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. But my question becomes should I use 1:1 or sqrt(L1):sqrt(L2)?

Comment: see here: http://www.linear.com/solutions/5092 from that I conclude that N1/N2 = sqrt(L1/L2) so it does not matter what you use.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the meaning of N1 and N2 in the LTspice for transformer is equal to the meaning of N1 and N2 in the above equivalent circuit? I'm not sure.

Comment: No I do not think it is as in (LT)Spice you model a transformer with 2 inductors and (to actually make it a transformer) add **mutual coupling** between those inductors as is shown in your Spice syntax example. The coupling factor K must be between -1 and 1, see http://ltwiki.org/?title=Mutual_Inductance  In your case I think making K = 1 will do the job, that would then simulate an ideal (not-lossy) transformer.

Comment: I want to use the model(the figure above) to represent my coupled inductor. I have measured it and I have L1, L2, and k.
The k value is not zero.
I don't know how to write my coupled inductor to SPICE model since I'm not sure what value of N1:N2 in the figure above.

And I am not sure if the three line syntax can represent the model with three inductors and one ideal transformer(figure above).

Comment: Set the ratio N1:N2 accoring to the suggestion above but set the absolute value for N1 to 1000 times higher than Lmag.

Comment: Hi winny. Thank you for your suggestion. I don't need absolute value of N1. I only need the ratio.
I have to input the inductance of N1 and N2 coil. You are talking about these two values?

Comment: @sinlin612 Is that a feature in (LT)spice I'm not aware of? I always set it to a high enough value to reject any useful magnitizing current from going there.

Comment: @winny can I see your syntax in LTspice? I thought that I don't need type N1 value in LTspice. N1:N2 is for the calculation of Lmag

Comment: I have only tried to do it manually and if you draw the magnitizing inductance separately, you need to come up with a high number for L1 to not sink magnitizing current there.

Answer (score 2):

You model a coupled inductor in Spice and other simulators by using a component called "k". "k" needs to be setup (quite simply) by stating which inductors it applies to and, it also needs a coupling factor i.e. by how much the magnetic field of one inductor couples to the other inductor. A negative value for k is the same as the output inductor being wound the opposite way i.e. it produces an inverted output waveform.

So, if one inductor is 1 henry and the other inductor is 10 milli henry (a 100:1 inductance ratio) there is an implied turns ratio of 10:1 when k = 1. If k = 0.5 there is still an implied turns ratio of 10:1. Both the below scenarios produce identical results: -

[image]

This is how I set up coupled inductors but there's no reason why you can't split an inductor into its leakage element and its coupled part. But why bother when k does that for you and it looks neater as a schematic symbol.

Comment: Thank you. So you think the three line ways is equal to the figure above if I know how to calculate all values in it?

I'm very curious how to calculate every components in above figure in the currect way.

Comment: Yes I do and I'll add some more detail to my answer as a demonstration.

Comment: I got very different result from the above model I memtioned.
I have a six-line netlist like this:<br/> 
Lk1 1 5 0.011u<br/> 
Lk2 2 6 0.006u<br/> 
Lm 5 3  0.277u<br/> 
L1 5 3 100<br/> 
L2 6 4 100<br/> 
k L1 L2 1.00<br/>
These values are from:<br/> \$Lm=\frac{N1}{N2}\sqrt{L11L22-(1-k^{2})*L11L22}\$<br/>
\$Lk1=L11-Lm\$<br/>
\$Lk2=L22-Lm{(\frac{N2}{N1})}^{2}\$<br/>
L11 and L22 are the inductance measured in one side by opening other sides.
Do I have any mistakes?

Comment: It's been decades since I used netlists to describe a circuit so I'm not able to understand what circuit you are describing.

Comment: My netlist is describing the figure I post above in the beginning.
I used N1:N2=\$\sqrt{L1}\$:\$\sqrt{L2}\$ to find all inductance, however I can't get the same results to the model with only three lines L1, L2, and k.

Comment: I don't know what "same results" means - I have no idea what results you are referring to and, as I said towards the end of my answer, "why bother". Having said that your schematic should be made to work exactly like the three line k model so I think you must be doing something wrong. How is N1 and N2 coupled together for instance - you give no clue about this and, bear in mind, I don't want to spend a lot of time on this because the proper solution is to use k and forget other methods and.....

Comment: ... although I haven't copied analysis answers into my answer, the two scenarios are, I believe equivalent to what you seem to be asking in your question.